# Leaving an empty line after environment and before enumeration

Tags: enumerate

If I have an enumeration, i.e. something like the following MWE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
            \item
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

What is the best way of letting the line where Definition stands be empty? I mean I would like to leave an empty line and on the next I want to start with the first item. At the moment I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some empty content just after the `\begin{definition}`. This will force the list to be set on a new line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  \mbox{}% ...or \leavevmode
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to use `\-` after `\begin{definition}` that forces a new line. Here is a MWE

```
 \documentclass{amsart}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

    \begin{document}
        \begin{definition}\-        
        \begin{enumerate}
                \item 
                \item
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really are talking about bytes here, then you might just as well use `~`, not ``\-``. Also, why do you include [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate)?

Comment: I just copy-pasted the MWE of @TheGeekGreek. You are right, that `enumerate`package does not need it :)